# How do I make a ForeignKey field use Multiple Dropdowns from the same list, and remove duplicates as they are selected, in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to set up a Django project that will reference a list of users.

In one of my models, I am using ForeignKey fields to point at the table of users.

I have several slots setup, linked to the table of users, and I would like to be able to select a user from that table when adding data. But I would also like the users name to be removed from the rest of the dropdowns if they are selected in one of the dropdowns.

For Example. I have 3 users in my table. John, Mark, Andy

In the entry page, I would like to have 3 dropdown fields. Each of them linked to the users table.

In the first field when I click it, all three users should pop up as options, John, Mark and Andy.

After selecting John, the second field should only give me the option to select Mark or Andy.

After selecting Mark for the second field, the third field should give the option to select Andy, or stay blank.

My models.py is setup like this:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Session(models.Model):
    Slot1 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot1')
    Slot2 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot2')
    Slot3 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot3')
    Slot4 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot4')
    Slot5 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot5')
    Slot6 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot6')
    Slot7 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot7')
    Slot8 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot8')
    Slot9 = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Slot9')
```

Ideally, this would work in the admin page, but if I have to setup a front facing version for it to work I will.